# convert a directory of csv.gz files to csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, python-requests, gzip

I've done that thing where I've confused myself beyond the point of any rational thought! I used `requests` in python 3.6 to download a bunch of files from a website.
All of the said files are in `csv.gz` format. I would like to convert these files to just `.csv` format.

Suppose I have 3 files in a folder:
    `blahblahblah1.csv.gz`
    `blahblahblah2.csv.gz`
    `blahblahblah3.csv.gz`

The documentation regarding gzip compression states:

```
import gzip
with gzip.open('somefile.gz', 'rt') as f:
text = f.read()
```

I would like to do something along the lines of:

```
import os
import gzip

for file in os.listdir(folder):
  convert file from csv.gz to .csv
```

Thank you for any help!!

Comment: I would just do this in the shell.  ‘ for x in *.csv.gz; do gunzip $x ; done ‘

Comment: @Doon you are forgetting that [POSIX shells sucks hard](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/9496/12167).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not pretty .... but it works :)

```
import gzip    

for filename in list_of files:
  with gzip.open(filename, 'rt') as f:
    data = f.read()
    with open(filename[:-3], 'wt') as f:
      f.write(data)
```

The `filename[:-3]` part is just a quick way to produce the name for the converted file from
`blahblahblah.csv.gz`  to `blahblahblah.csv`